# What UI controls are used by the sparrow app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am starting out with os x and cocoa programming and I'm trying to figure out how the sidebar on the sparrow mail app was put together.

What controls were used?  Is the leftmost area with the grey background an `NSTableView` or something else?

Comment: Unless a Sparrow dev is here and willing to share (not likely), this question is really just looking for guesses.

Answer (score 2):

This may not help in your specific case but you can open up an application bundle (control-click and show package contents) to see the files that make up the app. In there will be a resources folder, and in there will be, usually, some interface builder files that you can open in Xcode (be careful!) and look at the layout and classes that were used.

If the interface is defined in code, this won't help you.